# AJAX / PHP voting system: Content not updating on first click

Tags: php, ajax

**TESTING ENVIRONMENT:** Windows 8 using the tool `XAMMP`. PHP and Mysql are up to date.

---

**MY KNOWLEDGE:** Starter.

---

**QUESTION:** I can't get the updated content immediately after the first click, only after the second, which can become pretty nasty considering I have two kind of buttons for my little voting system. Yes, I said a lot not alot : ) 
What is the cause for this predicament and how can I fix this?

---

**WHAT I TRIED:** Checked my developer tools `network analysis` and I get a status 200 with the correct value for every click. When using my firefox `DOM inspector view` I saw something unusual: upon the first click only `#votes` is marked in orange probably denoting that it has been affected. However, only on the second attempt on the same button both divs, `#votes and #progress`, get marked orange in addition with the updated values. So I expect it does on second click but not on the first one. Then I refreshed my page and tried something else. I clicked on "bad" and this time the second click landed on "good" with bad updating the value in the DOM. It seems as if the entire process is split and does not happen simultaneously which is why I speculate that:

1. Click 1: *Sends data to php.*
2. Click 2: *Gets the data from php and displays it on the DOM.*

The PHP code itself in conjunction with my database and HTML (if set to submit) works perfectly fine so I dont assume there is anything wrong on the server side. Connection to the database is set. My sessions work perfectly. No errors.

My console shows 0 javascript errors.

***Test 1 :*** `I commented out my entire php code and set up a testing variable with a simple string` and changed the values in my code below accordingly. To my suprise, on clicking it immediately took the data and display the content of my testing variable.

***Test 2 ::*** `I removed the php codes from the two div tags` which you will see below. They act as placeholders that show the current value before any AJAX happens. I removed those and I get an update on first click as the container was first empty. Although, on second click and toggling between good and bad happened to be a mess again.

***Test 2 ::*** Placing jquery and my AJAX script in the `head` of the document did not do the job either (just to be on the safe side). Prior it was before the `</body>` tag

---

- *I access the returned json object through my callback parameter named `data` which then inserts html and css via jquery into the respective div containers.*
- *Converted the jquery below to pure javascript but no positive change could be observed.*

---

**JAVASCRIPT / AJAX**

```
function vote(type) {
    $.get('php/core/voting_system_function.php', {vote:type}, function(data) {
    $('#votes').html(data.votes_sum);
    $('#progress').css('width', data.progress);
    }, 'json');
}
```

---

---

**HTML**

- *The `buttons onclick event` feeds the data on to the parameter within my vote functions which then sends it to `{vote:type}` and then to my php file. This allows me to do several checks to see if the click was either 'good' or 'bad' and substract or add data accordingly in my database.*
- `#votes` and `#progress`

---

```
<div id="quality_meter">
    <div id="progress" style="width:<?php echo $progress ?>"></div>
</div>
<div id='votes'><?php echo $votes_sum ?></div>
```

---

---

- *The connection to the database is correct and readable through a require.*
- *The script works assuming the user actually logged in as they cant access the page otherwise. As you can see I am making use of two session variables.*
- *As you can see, I am making checks to see which button has been clicked and query accordingly.*
- *The last bit of the code returns a json object through an associative array with the data stored by the variables you see there which is `votes_sum` and `progress`. I use `json_encode` to return the json representation of my value.*

Comment: is the response body of the first click correct and contains what you expect? (regardless of the HTTP 200 OK status)

Comment: @STTLCU yes it contains the value of the button I clicked which is sent to the .php file it seems. The php file is also shown in the status with the value appended at the end of the url. It seems post works but getting the content only on second click

Comment: 200, GET, URL?vote=good or bad, localhost, json. Testing on firefox

Comment: what is your PHP supposed to return? Is the RESPONSE body the exact same for the first and second click event?

Comment: @STTLCU the exact same. My php is supposed to return the json object after encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say you're not getting the response until the second click, do you mean the "votes_sum" in the `votes` div isn't updating with the latest votes?

The reason for this is that you calculate the `$votes_sum` value before you call the `voting_system()` function which is what updates the votes count, then after `voting_system()` you move the `$votes_sum` - unchanged - to the `$output` array.

Comment: that is pretty nasty. I will check it out

Comment: True. This is the cause. `$votes_sum` gets initialized with `$votes_sum = array_sum($votes);` *before* you update the votes, and then it is never updated to the point where you output it. So you output the *old value before change*.

Comment: @MajidFouladpour it worked! you were right. That was the issue!