# Difference when creating object properties that have curly brackets

Tags: javascript

What is the differences between:

```
_object = {
   alpha: true,
   beta: for (a in c) {...},
   omega: function x{...} 
}
```

and

```
_object = {
   alpha: {true}, 
   beta: {for (a in c) {...}},
   omega: { function x{...} }
}
```

I would like to know why we use curly braces when we are dealing with long code within an object. Is it because we are dealing with objects inside objects where the first one is just dealing with properties? Are there any other concerns?

Comment: The difference is that all three properties in the second are invalid syntax. In the first, the definition of `beta` is also invalid. A property must be a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your code is pseudo code here is functional code:

```
_object = {
  alpha: true, 
  beta: {a: "word"},
  omega: false
}

console.log(_object);
```

Go put this in a fiddle and look at the object. The 'beta' is an object in the correct syntax. The reason you would do this is to get all of the benefits of an object over a primitive type.

Comment: sorry people are being mean about your question. It would help next time to put functional code. ;-)

Comment: Usually my questions are like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32349516/ajax-php-voting-system-content-not-updating-on-first-click but sometimes I have not much to write other than a simple question which then gets downvoted : (

Comment: And often I get confused about little things that I knew before but forgot during coding. It is weird.

Comment: I understand! Coding is tough, thank god for stackoverflow. :D

Comment: @Asbolutely. I just wish there was a stupidFlow for people with stupid questions during mind blocks ; )

Comment: Oh and as a little cookie check this out  (switch case) http://www.sitepoint.com/shorthand-javascript-techniques/ again thanks and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Where a statement is expected, `{` starts a code block.

Where an expression is expected, `{` starts an object literal. In your case, since you are using the `{` following a key, it starts an object literal. An object literal must be of the form `{ key: value, ... }`. Since none of the examples you give follow this form, they are invalid syntax, and will result in a parsing error.

Comment: So basically beta is invalid. As well as all three in the second.

Comment: omega in the first is valid then since it is a method, and alpha is a property with a value. So everything else such as for loops cant be added unless I wrap those in a function. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: functions are objects. If you put a for loop inside a function and pass it as a value it is stored as an object. "functions are first class"